# Changing image in script with a transition effect

Tags: javascript, css

I am using this code:

```
<script>
    const body = document.querySelector("grayallbg");
    const li = document.querySelectorAll("span");
    

    li.forEach(el => {
        el.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
            let bg = el.getAttribute("data-bg");
            grayallbg.style.background = `url(${bg})no-repeat center /cover`;
        });
    });
</script>
```

And it swaps fine, but I want it to ease in or fade.

I have tried to add a class, surround it with css selectors and I cannot target the images that swap.

Comment: you can use CSS transition property or if you are down use jquery ```fadeIn()``` method

Answer (score 2):

For a pure CSS solution use a [CSS var()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var) to store the *hover image* with some [transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition):

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  transition: background 200ms ease;
}

.a {
  background-image: url(https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/130/200/300.jpg?hmac=ax-dkx2e5CJww9f5IfH-mUHr_9eNBKUNGHcA46-0oB0);
}

.b {
  background-image: url("https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/681/200/300.jpg?hmac=RrSjLfU9adr2teGTAalv7b6XXsDyaPxIWyoBm30Qn5A");
}

.box:hover {
  background-image: var(--background);
}
```

```html
<div class="a box" style="--background:url(https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/442/200/300.jpg?hmac=0CJZGZR5EIN-e7Q7zmUijm-B6pp4X4C57kuL4kR02ik)"></div>

<div class="b box" style="--background:url(https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/1025/200/300.jpg?hmac=IOMIDjfOXbZ-vD59diaXLcQcq5g6Xo3Zg_gRF9UmwL0)"></div>
```

Comment: The way the script is, it has 14 different images that will replace that spot.  I think I need to add something to the java, I just cannot find the right combination.